# Automating Temenos deployment

Tags: jboss, temenos

My goal is to automate the T24 deployment. Therefore I would like to know if the application BUILD.CONTROL (called via **sh tRun EX**) can be started in a non-interactive mode (as opposed to Input mode), where all the required data and credentials are passed as cmd parameters (or in a config file). This way I would like to start this process via Jenkins.

Comment: interesting question; I have never seen it done before anywhere. that question has also never occurred to me. I think there are deployment procedures using design studio to publish to T24, but I have not explored that to give a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 0):

To automate Temenos T24 (Transact) deployment you need to use these 2 utilities that Temenos have built exactly for this purpose:

```
tRun T24PackageInstaller 
tRun packageDataInstaller
```

They will deploy the jar file built by Maven from your local 't24-packager-tafj' project created in T24 Design Studio (Temenos Customized Eclipse IDE).

BUILD.CONTROL in my opinion is far outdated and obsolete, you might be able to get it working through OFS, but it could be too specific and possibly will not work when invoked that way.